# Docker: Stderr:fatal error: runtime: out of memory on AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Each time I am trying to build and deploy my React Project on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using Docker, I am getting this error:

```sh
Stderr:fatal error: runtime: out of memory
```

The project is the basic react project and nothing more, serving it via nginx. What might be the reason of this error? And how do I resolve it. Please note, I have emptied my S3 bucket and have restarted the appServer too, to try and resolve any unnecessary memory or cache use. And I am able to successfully build and run this file locally. The logs are as follows:

```sh
Step 1/9 : FROM node:alpine as builder
 ---> eb56d56623e5
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR '/app'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 41d7415dae07
Step 3/9 : COPY package.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 95877ba9972c
Step 4/9 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c366758de80f
Step 5/9 : COPY . .
 ---> 5697eace7031
Step 6/9 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in 52cc1a3e6ac0

> react-project-frontend@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build

Creating an optimized production build...

2022/03/03 13:14:45.346275 [WARN] failed to execute command: docker build -t aws_beanstalk/staging-app /var/app/staging/, retrying...
2022/03/03 13:14:45.425369 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker build -t aws_beanstalk/staging-app /var/app/staging/
2022/03/03 13:14:47.001398 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: failed to build docker image: Command /bin/sh -c docker build -t aws_beanstalk/staging-app /var/app/staging/ failed with error exit status 2. Stderr:fatal error: runtime: out of memory
```

Answer (score 0):

You docker image does not enough memory allocated:

In the ElasticBeanstalk application environment `Dockerrun.aws.json`, you can increase the memory allocation (`"memory": 80` to e.g. `"memory": 100`):

```
"containerDefinitions": [
  {
  "name": "request_repeater",
  "image": "my/image",
  "essential": true,
  "memory": 80, <- change this
```

Also, maybe you need to change the instance type. For example the `t2.nano` has a max memory of `0.5 GB`

You can do this in **Modify capacity** settings when you are creating your application, or edit in *Configuration > Capacity* setting on the current env configuration.